# Adding Post-build Actions Sonar causes Jenkins build to fail

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

Using Jenkins ver. 1.494; [Jenkins Sonar Plugin 2.0.1](http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341); Sonar server 3.4.1.
[Maven job.](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+Sonar+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonaronJenkinsJob-TriggeringaSonarAnalysiswithMaven)

Adding Post-build Actions `Sonar` causes Jenkins build to fail (ERROR: Failed to parse POMs).
Deleting Sonar action then again makes it pass.

```
Sync complete, took 35 ms
Parsing POMs
[Atlas_Phevos] $ java -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -cp /home/jenkins/jenkins-home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-agent-1.2.jar:/home/jenkins/jenkins-home/tools/Maven/Maven304/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main /home/jenkins/jenkins-home/tools/Maven/Maven304 /usr/local/tomcat-6.0.32/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.19.jar /home/jenkins/jenkins-home/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-1.2.jar 60147
ERROR: Failed to parse POMs
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/jenkins/jenkins-home/workspace/Atlas_Phevos"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:244)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:216)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:763)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:353)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenProcessFactory.newProcess(AbstractMavenProcessFactory.java:223)
    at hudson.maven.ProcessCache.get(ProcessCache.java:231)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:670)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:586)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1543)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:148)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:65)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:453)
    ... 12 more
Skipping sonar analysis due to bad build status FAILURE
Sending e-mails to: ____
Finished: FAILURE
```

I haven't put [updated setting.xml](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven) on Jenkins server, I guess Jenkins should take its own configuration for Sonar (sever, JDBC connection etc.)

UPDATE: Problem still exists. I tried several jobs to start sonar analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your exception it looks like Jenkins cannot find your JDK. In your job configuration you can expand the Sonar properties. Make sure that a valid JDK from your Jenkins config is selected under the `JDK` option.

While you are looking at the properties make sure the pom file specified under `Root POM` is correct.

Try that...

Comment: As I said above, without Sonar Post-build Action there's no problem.
I checked JDK. It has been jdk1.6.0_25

Comment: Yeah, but as the Sonar Post-Build Action has its own JDK configuration, this still would make sense.

Comment: I took a look at my own sonar protocols and I don't have any "Parsing POMs" comments there, also the command executed there is a mvn call, not java, not sure what to make of that... perhaps you could post your job configuration here (its saved in your jenkins/jobs folder as an xml file), and i would cross reference it with my own...

Comment: One more idea, is your job a maven job or a free-style job? I use free-style jobs for my Sonar analysis, I think I had some trouble getting it to work with maven jobs...

Comment: I explicitly added JDK for sonar bost-build action. And the problem is solved.